Power apps combobox default selection in edit mode
In the power apps I am using combobox to fletch the users name details from another list (UserList) it contains 150 records.
While adding the record the combobox showing the all names, but, when editing the records it not showing the data, but the date is already updated in list(DataList).
Hear I am using the Gallery Search to fletch the records and editing the record.
If I select the record, for some records it shows the data in combobox.
Is there any delegation to show the data in combobox.
In my main list(DataList) we have 5k records.
In the power apps I am using combobox to fletch the users name details from another list it contains 150 records.
While adding the record the combobox showing the all names, but, when editing the records it not showing the data, but the date is already updated in list.
For some records it shows the data in combobox.
Is there any delegation to show the data in combobox.

Can please you add your code for the Item property, so that we can have a look
